# Expand more text by pressing icon

Tags: html, css

[image]I have a big text, and when I press on icon(down), it deploys, but how can roll up it using another icon(up)?

```css
.read-more-state {
  display: none;
}

.read-more-target {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  transition: .25s ease;
}

.read-more-state:checked~.read-more-wrap .read-more-target {
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: inherit;
  max-height: 999em;
}

.read-more-state~.read-more-trigger:before {
  content: 'Show more';
}

.read-more-state:checked~.read-more-trigger:before {
  content: 'Show less';
}

.read-more-state:checked~.read-more-trigger:before {
  background: url(up.svg);
}

.read-more-trigger {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 .5em;
  color: #666;
  font-size: .9em;
  line-height: 2;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: .25em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="read-more-state" id="post-1" />
  <p class="read-more-wrap">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. <span class="read-more-target">Libero fuga facilis vel consectetur quos sapiente deleniti eveniet dolores tempore eos deserunt officia quis ab? Excepturi vero tempore minus beatae voluptatem!</span></p>
  <label for="post-1" class="read-more-trigger"><img src="down.svg"></label>
</div>
```

But another question, just show me right way, I need to see all text in computer screen, but in responsive version it is needed to hide some text and after pressing down.svg text needs to deploy.

Comment: please upload here your down.svg and up.svg image. i can't see your images.

Comment: @DogukanCavus this is svg, that`s why I can`t upload here them

Comment: svg is not relevant to the problem

Comment: @DogukanCavus I uploaded it. you can see it

Comment: @Smollet777 So can you help me in this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`img` &`.read-more-trigger` just for styling because jpg is big.
You can [rotate](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotate) element (image/svg). With transition it's smoother.

`.read-more-state:checked~.read-more-trigger>img`

And don't forget transition to default
`.read-more-trigger>img`

```css
img {
  height: 100%;
}

.read-more-trigger {
  height: 20px;
}

.read-more-state:checked~.read-more-trigger>img {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  transition: transform 0.65s ease-in-out;
}

.read-more-trigger>img {
  transition: transform 0.65s ease-in-out;
}

.read-more-state {
  display: none;
}

.read-more-target {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  transition: .25s ease;
}

.read-more-state:checked~.read-more-wrap .read-more-target {
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: inherit;
  max-height: 999em;
}

.read-more-state~.read-more-trigger:before {
  content: 'Show more';
}

.read-more-state:checked~.read-more-trigger:before {
  content: 'Show less';
}

.read-more-state:checked~.read-more-trigger:before {
  background: url(up.svg);
}

.read-more-trigger {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 .5em;
  color: #666;
  font-size: .9em;
  line-height: 2;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: .25em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="read-more-state" id="post-1" />
  <p class="read-more-wrap">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. <span class="read-more-target">Libero fuga facilis vel consectetur quos sapiente deleniti eveniet dolores tempore eos deserunt officia quis ab? Excepturi vero tempore minus beatae voluptatem!</span></p>
  <label for="post-1" class="read-more-trigger"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVbiS.jpg"></label>
</div>
```

P.S. your "down" arrow here is actualy "up" arrow. But it does not matter here.

Comment: Thank you very much! You helped me. Can I ask one more question?

Comment: @Juicy134  You may post as many good questions as you like to Stack Overflow, each should really be one question if possible.

Comment: @Juicy134 about responsivnes? Your checkbox is responsible for displaing div. You need to find a way to set it `checked` by default on desired resolutions. May be with JS. Idk.